# How to pass paramters to HTML file in node.js?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I have a code like `res.sendfile('./home.html',{user:req.user})` and I want to access the `user parameter` in the HTML file. I don't want to use a template engine. How do I do this?

Comment: You're asking on how to *create* a template engine, while saying you don't want to *use* one. Dependencies aren't bad things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to use a template engine, you manually need to read in the file, then push whatever value you want into a placeholder...

```
var fs = require('fs');
...
  fs.readFile('./home.html', {encoding:'utf8'}, function(err, file){
    if (err) return res.end('ERROR');
    file = file.replace('%USER%', req.user);
    res.end(file);
  });
```

What you are describing is precisely what templates are for... now, if you want these variables to be available in JS.. then you may want a client "var cfg = %%CLIENT_CONFIG%%;" somewhere at the top, and you can JSON.stringify your config, and do the same replace.

If you want a lightweight templating engine you can use manually, you probably want to use lodash's template method.

Comment: but what is %USER% here? I'm getting an error like has no method replace

Comment: %USER% is placeholder you want to replace